# Problem about norm and condition number

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let be A an invertible matrix. Show that for the operator norm induced by euclidean $\cal2$-norm $cond_2(A^TA)=(cond_2(A))^2$. There is a hint to consider some matrix decomposition.

**My attempt:**

Since $cond_2(A)=\Vert A\Vert_2 \Vert A^{-1}\Vert_2$ and $\Vert A\Vert_2=\sqrt {\lambda_{max}}$, where $\lambda_{max}$ is the biggest eigenvalue of $AA^T$. We obtain $$(cond_2(A))^2= \frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}}$$
Furhtermore due to the hint I thought to consider a QR decomposition(though I am not sure if this is helpful).We obtain $$cond_2(A^TA)=\Vert A^TA\Vert_2\Vert (A^TA)^{-1}\Vert_2=\Vert A^TA\Vert_2\Vert A^{-1}A^{-T}\Vert_2=\Vert R^TQ^T QR \Vert_2=\Vert R^{-1}Q^{-1}Q^{-T}R^{-T}\Vert_2=\Vert R^TR\Vert_2\Vert (R^TR)^{-1}\Vert_2$$ I used here the fact $\Vert Qx\Vert=\Vert x\Vert$
but I  think this does not lead anywhere, some help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $UDU^\top$ is the eigendecomposition of $A^\top A$ (here $U$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal) then $(A^\top A)^\top A^\top A = UD^2 U^\top$.
$$\text{cond}(A^\top A) = \| A^\top A\|_2 \|(A^\top A)^{-1}\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(UD^2U^\top)\cdot \lambda_{\max}(U D^{-2} U^\top)} = \frac{\lambda_{\max}(A^\top A)}{\lambda_{\min}(A^\top A)}.$$
Here $\lambda_{\max}(\cdot)$ is a "function" that returns the largest eigenvalue.

Note that you need to use invertibility of $A$ and positive semidefinite-ness of $A^\top A$ to ensure $0<\lambda_{\min} \le \cdots \le \lambda_{\max}$ so that the formula $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A)}$ makes sense.

Comment: I am not given that A is positive semi definite

Comment: @JohnDoe I didn't say that, I said $A^\top A$ is PSD.

Comment: sorry for that! One question left: why $cond (A^TA) = \Vert(A^TA)^TA^TA \Vert \Vert ((A^TA)^TA^TA)^{-1} \Vert$ or is this equal to my stated equation above?

Comment: @JohnDoe Sorry, that was a typo, will fix.

Comment: All right, every thing is clear now. cheers